# Ad Hoc build not registering push notifications

Tags: iphone, sdk, notifications, push

I have an application which I would like to enable push notifications on. I have had it working with my developer build and then I wanted to make an ad hoc build.

I installed the Ad Hoc build on my iPhone and it is working fine. Then I tried an iPhone in the family but it does not register for push notifications. The application is not showed in settings (where settings for push notifications are made), there is no alert asking the user to activate push notifications on the first launch and the device is not registered in my MySQL database.

I am using the PHP library "Easy APNs" and it should be set to use both development and production certificates - anyways, I don't think that's where the issue is as there are no actions from to phone to try to register for push notifications.

Does anyone have an idea what I can be doing wrong?

**EDIT:** PHP script for sending push notifications to all registered devices with Easy APNs.

```
// GET ALL DEVICES
$result = $db->query("SELECT pid FROM apns_devices WHERE status = 'active'");
$pids = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $pids[] = intval($row['pid']);
}

$apns->newMessage($pids);
$apns->addMessageAlert($_POST['apns_message']);
$apns->addMessageSound('chime');
```

Comment: When I read the mobileprovision files (under "Settings" on the iPhone), I can see that the mobileprovisioning file on my iPhone is newer than the one on the other iPhone. Mine is from today while the other is from the 20th of February.
Could this be the issue and if so, how would I make sure that the other iPhone gets the newest mobileprovisioning file?

Comment: Look in the organizer for provisioning profiles installed.

Comment: Are u using production push certificate?

Comment: @malinois, I will try to see if that's where the issue is and come back with response wheter or not I solved it. @honcheng I should be. I am using Easy APNs which is a PHP "library" for sending out push notifications. There you can set both development and production certificates and they are both set.

Comment: I tried removing all mobileprovision files and distribute the application through ad hoc again and now the application asks to enable push notifications and the device is registered in my database. When sending push notifications it does only send to my own device and not the other iPhone. Does anyone have an idea why this is?

Comment: The other iphone is in the provisioning profile ?

Comment: Yes, it is. I thought that was the issue aswell but it does not seem to be.

Comment: I have managed to get it to send push notifications to all devices. For some reason, the PHP script provided by Easy APNs (or one of the users) did not work so I rewrote it and now it works. You can find it in my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in the mobile provisioning files. Deleting all my provisioning files, redownload them and rebuild worked. Take a look at the original post for a way to send out push notifications to all registered devides with Easy APNs.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Had to regenerate the Distribution provisioning profile in the iOS Developer portal, "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles".

1. Under "Provisioning Profiles", select "Distribution".
2. Select your distribution profile.
3. Click Edit.
4. Click Generate.